# Destroy cookie not working in sub directory

Tags: php, cookies, destroy

I think there might be something I don't get about cookies. I'm trying to destroy a cookie when I click on a button but the cookie stays. I know that instructions for cookies must be before html codes, so I created a new php page with no html code, logout.php:

```
<?php

if (isset($_COOKIE['pseudocookie'])) {
    setcookie('pseudocookie', '', time()-300); 
}

if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start(); 
}

session_destroy();
session_unset();

header('Location: ../index.php'); ?>
```

And I'm calling the page from index.php with a simple button :

```
<input type="button" id="ButSignout" value="Sign out" onclick="window.location.href='pages/logout.php'" />
```

I did some test, the php page is well loaded, if I try to delete the cookie directly from index.php, it works. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

---

The cookie was created with:

```
setcookie('pseudocookie','Pseudo cookie',time()+$expire, null, null, false, true);
```

---

When I try this code in logout.php without the header, I can see the new value of the cookie printed.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['pseudocookie'])) {
    //setcookie('pseudocookie', '', time()-300); 

    echo "test";
    setcookie('pseudocookie','Cookie cookie',time()+3600);
    echo $_COOKIE['pseudocookie'];
    unset($_COOKIE['pseudocookie']);
}
```

But when I get back on index.php where the cookie is printed, it shows his prior value. It seems that the cookie gets automatically its previous value when index.php is reloaded, although there is no setcookie in the index.php code...

Comment: How did you create the cookie?  (Display that code)

Comment: setcookie('pseudocookie','Pseudo cookie',time()+$expire, null, null, false, true);
$expire is a time variable (int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

I believe the problem may come from the way you created the cookie.  You used a `null` **$path** instead of `/`, so that cookie may not be available at `/pages` and therefore your `if (isset($_COOKIE['pseudocookie']))` condition is failing in `/pages/logout.php`.

You can verify this by echoing inside the if isset.

Comment: I already tried it, but to be sure I just did it again : I can see the echo in the isset test but the cookie is still not deleted. I just tried to create the cookie without any parameters after the time, without success.

Comment: Then the problem is the opposite.  You're setting the cookie for only the pages directory and not the / directory.  Use `/` in both setcookie calls and it should work fine